Airflow Mark as success/failure callback
I'm playing a bit with Airflow alerting mechanism, but I can't find anything on how to do use a callback for when tasks/dags state is set manually.
I'm primarly using the DockerOperator.
I've tried the on_failure_callback and on_success_callback but they only get triggered when the task state is set by Airflow's scheduler.
I'm I missing something ? Is there any way to actually have a callback for when tasks/dags state is set manually ?

Which version of Airflow are you using ?

@vdolez latest 2.10.2

It seems these events are handled by the task Executor, so when you use the website (i.e the REST api) to change a state, you only change the value in the Database without waking up the task Executor. What's your actual Use Case ? Manually changing a state imply that you can also manually start any procedure you want. I don't think Airflow Listeners will work differently from Callbacks.

@vdolez basically, our alerting process creates Issues on Jira in case of a failure, when there's a "false positive" alert, we can only set the task state to success manually.
I'd like to automatically close the issue when it's state is set manually

One way to achieve this would be by developing your own Airflow Plugin to add this feature inside the UI.
